# Identifying similar XYZ points between two sets of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two .csv files of XYZ points, A and B, where I want to find the closest matching XYZ point in B to each individual XYZ point in A and pair those two sets of points together. Both csv files have the same 'X', 'Y', 'Z' headers.

My current method is to convert my csv files to lists and to use a for loop to loop through and calculate the distances between the two lists of XYZ values.

My issue now is being able to actually pair the two sets of points together.

Example Data: My actual data contains 1000s of points

```
A = [[-24.5, -12.5, 53.0],[-36.6, -32.5, 50.0],[-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]]
B = [[-24, -12, 52],[-26, -13, 48], [-36, -33, 50], [49, 10, 53], [87, 59, 49]]

match = []
for x in A:
    for y in B:
        dist =abs(abs(x[0])-abs(y[0]))+abs(abs(x[1])-abs(y[1]))+abs(abs(x[2])-abs(y[2])
```

My ideal output would look something like this:

```
[-24.5, -12.5, 53] : [-24, -12, 52]
[-36.6, -32.5, 50.0] : [-36, -33, 50]
[-26.62, -13.5, 49.0] : [-26, -13, 50]
```

Am I going about this in the right way or is there a better way of doing this say in pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of pairing the set of points is to create a list of lists like this: `[x, y]` where `x` represents point in A and `y` represents point in B

So, your final solution will be:

```py
[[[-24.5, -12.5, 53.0], [-24, -12, 52]]
[[-36.6, -32.5, 50.0], [-36, -33, 50]]
[[-26.62, -13.5, 49.0], [-24, -12, 52]]
[[-26.62, -13.5, 49.0], [-26, -13, 48]]]
```

This is a three dimensional list where each row represents a set of points (each point being a list)

#### Code:

```py
match = []
for x in A:
    for y in B:
        dist = abs(abs(x[0])-abs(y[0]))+abs(abs(x[1])-abs(y[1]))+ abs(abs(x[2])) - abs(y[2])
        # Replace the value in this check
        if dist < 5:
            match.append([x, y])

print(match)
```

It will generate a similar output as shown above

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

# Define a distance function between two points
def distance(x, y):
    return math.sqrt(sum([(x[i] - y[i])**2 for i,_ in enumerate(x)]))


# For a point x, loop over candidates and find the closest point y
# Use tuples so we can refer to the y value with shortest distance by 
# sorting over the latter
def get_closest(x):
    distances = ((y, distance(x,y)) for y in B)
    closest = sorted(distances, key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0]
    return closest

# Loop over x points and find each of their closest points
# Output results as a list of (x,y) tuples
def match_up(A, B):
    pairs = [(x, get_closest(x)) for x in A]
    return pairs


A = [[-24.5, -12.5, 53.0],[-36.6, -32.5, 50.0],[-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]]
B = [[-24, -12, 52],[-26, -13, 48], [-36, -33, 50], [49, 10, 53], [87, 59, 49]]

print(match_up(A,B))
```

-- Result --- :

```
[([-24.5, -12.5, 53.0], [-24, -12, 52]),
 ([-36.6, -32.5, 50.0], [-36, -33, 50]),
 ([-26.62, -13.5, 49.0], [-26, -13, 48])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which

- stores the results in pandas;
- flattens the for-loop by using products;
- uses built-in distance methods (you can also replace it with something more suitable [from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html)).

```py
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import math as m


A = [[-24.5, -12.5, 53.0], [-36.6, -32.5, 50.0], [-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]]
B = [[-24, -12, 52], [-26, -13, 48], [-36, -33, 50], [49, 10, 53], [87, 59, 49]]


results = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "distance"])

for pair in product(A, B):
    x, y = pair[0], pair[1]

    dist = m.dist(x, y)
    results = results.append(
        {'A': x, 'B': y, 'distance': dist}, ignore_index=True
    )


results
```

This will produce a dataframe showing the pairs

```py
    A   B   distance
0   [-24.5, -12.5, 53.0]    [-24, -12, 52]  1.224745
1   [-24.5, -12.5, 53.0]    [-26, -13, 48]  5.244044
2   [-24.5, -12.5, 53.0]    [-36, -33, 50]  23.695991
3   [-24.5, -12.5, 53.0]    [49, 10, 53]    76.866768
4   [-24.5, -12.5, 53.0]    [87, 59, 49]    132.516037
5   [-36.6, -32.5, 50.0]    [-24, -12, 52]  24.145600
6   [-36.6, -32.5, 50.0]    [-26, -13, 48]  22.284748
7   [-36.6, -32.5, 50.0]    [-36, -33, 50]  0.781025
8   [-36.6, -32.5, 50.0]    [49, 10, 53]    95.616996
9   [-36.6, -32.5, 50.0]    [87, 59, 49]    153.786248
10  [-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]   [-24, -12, 52]  4.256102
11  [-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]   [-26, -13, 48]  1.278437
12  [-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]   [-36, -33, 50]  21.661819
13  [-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]   [49, 10, 53]    79.288299
14  [-26.62, -13.5, 49.0]   [87, 59, 49]    134.780393
```

And then you can select the best versions with this small function

```py
def show_nearest(results, column):

    results.loc[:, column] = results[column].astype(str)

    return results.groupby(column, as_index=False).apply(
        lambda x: x.iloc[x["distance"].argmin()]
    )


show_nearest(results, "A")
```